# MySQL - Update/Set a column in one table equal to MAX value from another table

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update, inner-join

I've found a number of hits for what I'm trying to do, but only when doing a `SELECT` and I haven't been able to get those methods to work with an `UPDATE`.

```
Table: Project
Site | I-Date | Status

Table: Schedule
Site | F-Date | Status
```

Here's the query I have now, but I want to guarantee that the project date is set only to the MAX date as there could be multiple entries for each site, but with different dates in `schedule`.

```
UPDATE project
    INNER JOIN schedule on project.site = schedule.site 
    SET project.i-date = schedule.f-date, project.status = 'complete'
    WHERE project.site = 'site123'
```

I tried doing this:

```
UPDATE project
    INNER JOIN schedule on project.site = schedule.site 
    SET project.i-date = MAX(schedule.f-date) as 'f-date', project.status = 'complete'
    WHERE project.site = 'site123'
```

but that didn't work. I suspect I need some different methods of joining but having trouble getting the right mixture.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about a subselect?

```
UPDATE project
SET 
    project.`i-date` = (
        SELECT MAX(`f-date`)
        FROM schedule
        WHERE schedule.site = project.site
    ),
    project.status = 'complete'
WHERE project.site = 'site123'
```

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE table_1
set column_1=(select max(salary) as salary from table_2)
where 1

Comment: Where are you taking the column salary from? This shows how you can solve the problem but adds nothing to @evilpenguins answer and is not properly formatted. Don't know who upvoted this.

Comment: Please review the other answer's before posting your's. As noted by @Philipp a very similar answer with better formatting and contextual names was done before yours. Thanks for your response, but take a look at the guidelines for answers (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and you'll find your feedback much more appreciated.